# Box Plot in R based on column names

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a data frame in following format where my variables are the column names.

```
a b c
1 2 3
2 3 4
1 4 1
```

I want to create a box plot based column names. Do I need to do any conversion for box plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can feed the entire frame to `boxplot` and each column will be plotted individually:

```
boxplot(my_df)
```

Comment: Can we do oneway anova test in above dataframe?

Comment: Sure, in this case you would `stack` the frame to get the column headers as categories: `oneway.test(values ~ ind, stack(my_df))`.  In this case 'values' and 'ind' are the columns assigned to the new frame by default.